# IOS UI tests without simulator or device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ui-testing

I want to write UI tests for ios.

can I run them (from xcode) without device or simulator as destination?

for example: I want to test click on btn and check if something happened, but not want that test run it on simulator or device.

(I know that in android you can use robolectric to do it).

Comment: So, where the tests are going to run?

Comment: Where is the UI if there is no simulator or device?

Comment: Something fake  like moq.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but there is no other solutions for it. You can only make a choice between device or simulator.